# Encrypting Login details for MySQL Database in VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Hey I've coded a Program with Login that connects to my MySql Database.
Since everyone has to Login before using it they have to connect to the Database in order to proof if the Login Details are correct.

To allow that connection I have store the Username and Password for that Database inside the Program:

```
datasource=myip;port=myport;username=username;password=password;database=database
```

I guess it wouldn't be hard at all for any hacker to find this username and password so is it possible to hide the login details somehow? I were able to crypt and decrypt it but I don't think that it would be too hard to even crack that.

How do others do it or is there a other way to connect to your database without the username and password in ur code?

Comment: use a REST api.

Comment: Are you going to have everyone connect to your database as the same user?  If not, I think you're going to need to have the username and password as config settings, probably with some UI for the user to enter them.  You may still want to encrypt the password, since the config would be plain text.

Comment: No, everyone connects with a different Username. There is no password needed since I HWID lock everything, logging in from a different Computer won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As Baseult indicates in the comments, the only way to stop someone breaking into your database is *not give it to them in the first place* - you keep the DB on your server, and other people access it by sending calls to a web service. Doesn't have to be RESTful

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments but why not use a generic login to connect to the database and restrict it with user names/passwords/hashes for the application via a user table in your database?